# python3 fastkml and multigeometries

Tags: python

How to create a multi geometry (with, for example, a multipoint and a line)
using fastkml library and python 3.6?
No one seems to have ever posted anything on this topic so I wonder if it is even possible.

My goal is to generate a single placemark that uses a complex geometry ie :

- 2 points
- one vector between the two points

it should then be encoded as a multigeometry in the final KML.

I have done further investigations. From now, i realized that the correct syntax is :

```
# create a line geometry using shapely
line = shapely.geometry.LineString([p1, p2])
# combine shapes into a geometrycollection
gc = shapely.geometry.collection.GeometryCollection([line, p1, p2])
# append the collection to the placemark geometry
p.geometry = gc
```

anyway a class type error still exist at runtime. Some investigations in fastkml geometry.py module exhibits some very interesting information in the import section:

```
try:
    from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon
    from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon
    from shapely.geometry.polygon import LinearRing
    #from shapely.geometry import GeometryCollection
    # Sean Gillies:
    # I deliberately omitted a geometry collection constructor because
    # there was almost no support in GEOS for operations on them. You
    # couldn't buffer a collection, for example, or find its difference
    # to another geometry. I've seen some signs of this changing in GEOS,
    # but until it does I don't think there's any point to the class.
    # It wouldn't be much more than a list of geometries.
    from pygeoif.geometry import GeometryCollection
    from shapely.geometry import asShape

except ImportError:
    from pygeoif.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon
    from pygeoif.geometry import MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon
    from pygeoif.geometry import LinearRing
    from pygeoif.geometry import GeometryCollection
    from pygeoif.geometry import as_shape as asShape
```

My understanding is that the fastkml lib alway creates a GeometryCollection object from pygeoif and not from shapely. It is confirmed by the fact that if imports are changed in :

```
from shapely.geometry import GeometryCollection  
# from pygeoif.geometry import GeometryCollection
```

everything goes fine and the kml file is created as expected.

It is amasing that this beahaviour seems to be made on purpose. At this time,  I still do not understand its exact justification. I know that changing a library source code is a bad idea. Maybe a better solution would rise ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would be helpful if you could provide additional background regarding what exactly you'd like to do, and what you've done so far (e.g. do you know how it's done with Python 2.X?)

Comment: thanks for your attention. I have modified the original question to make it more explicit.